# Twisted Pair input routing on PCB

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, layout, high-speed

I have a twisted pair input to the IN+ and IN- pins of the [MAX9278](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9278-MAX9282.pdf) deserializers.

The Parallel data output of the deserializer consists of 4 LVDS data channels and 1 LVDS Clock channel to a 3.1" TFT whose Pixel Clock is calculated to be as 27MHz.

So, I guess the twisted pair inputs IN+ and IN- would also be 27MHz. Am I correct is assuming so?

In that case, what impedance should be maintained between the IN+ and IN- twisted pair input signals to the deserializer? Should I maintain the 100ohms impedance just like if it was a coax input or what should I do?

Comment: The serialized data rate depends on which mode the link is set to. The modes how data is serialized are explained in datasheet page 29 onwards. In reality, it will be about 1 gigabit, why is the exact number necessary? It's a transport chip, you encode it with one chip and this chip decodes it, you can simply ise it without knowing the exact details. Impedance is explained on page 63.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *So, I guess the twisted pair inputs IN+ and IN- would also be 27MHz.
> Am I correct is assuming so?*

No, that's not correct. The bandwidth of the transmitted serialized data will be a little over \$N\$ x the bandwidth of each deserialized output. It's a little over \$N\$ times because the serializer adds synchronizing markers into the combined serialized data frame.

So, converting the problem to bits per second, if you combined 4 serial data streams of 1 bit per second, the serialized data will be 4 bits per second plus a little bit more (for the sync bits needed to decode the data). Obviously you are not running at 1 bit per second; I am just using that as an example.

> *In that case, what impedance should be maintained between the IN+ and
> IN- twisted pair input signals to the deserializer? Should I maintain
> the 100ohms impedance just like if it was a coax input or what should
> I do?*

It needs to match the transmission/characteristic impedance of the twisted pair interface cable.

Comment: So, if my PCLK of the LVDS TFT Data is 27MHz, then my twisted pair input signal speed would be around 108MHz?

Comment: @Newbie it would be slightly higher than 108 MHz. The extra is due to synch pulses added to the combined serialized data stream.

Comment: Not true. LVDS panel interfaces send 7 bits per lane on single reference clock. 27MHz clock thus equates to 189 Mbps per LVDS lane.

Comment: How to arrive at the Clock speed at IN+ and IN- ?

Comment: @Justme, could you help me to arrive at the input speed of the IN+ and IN- ?

Comment: Quick calculation : 27 MHz clock. 7 bits per clock per data lane. 4 data lanes. That's 768 Mbps of raw TFT data. Add 8b10b coding and serdes rate is already almost a gigabit.

Comment: 4 data lanes * 7 bits per clock per lane * 27MHz = 756Mbps. Is this correct?

Comment: @newbie if the chip encodes 7 bits at a rate of 27 million times per second and, there are four lots of this then the payload data rate has to be 756 Mbps + overhead and the overhead might account for another 10%.

Comment: @Justme, could you tell me from where you got the "7 bits per clock per data lane". I tried to search but unable to find.

Comment: @Newbie that's how LVDS video links work, you can look at datasheet pages 28 and 29, or datasheet of your TFT panel.

Comment: Sorry, just now realized that I have not accepted the answer. Could you please also explain the impedance values that needs to be maintained for twisted pair inputs and Coax inputs? Is it 100ohms differential impedance between the twisted pair and 50ohms for COAX?

Comment: @Newbie it's usually a 2:1 relationship between screened twisted pair and coax of roughly the same outer dimensions. But some twisted pair cables are over 100 ohms and there are plenty of coax cables that are 75 ohms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.